# Run Specific Application without User Interface in C#

Tags: c#

I want to write a service that runs an application (assume firefox.exe) without user interface.

I mean you can see it in task manager but no window is opened. 
I have tested this code but no success and it will open firefox's ui:

```
var p = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        UseShellExecute = false,
        FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe",
        WindowStyle =  ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = false
    }
};
p.Start();
```

Comment: this will not work, until the program you want to launch allows you to do that.  i.e. if the creator of the program  did not specify a command (or flag) which allows you to do so, this will not work.

Comment: _"I mean you can see it in task manager but no window is opened"_ isn't that what you want?

Comment: I mean when the service will run, it will run firefox in background and no one can see its windows. but it is running and is listed in task manager   @Lloyd

Comment: So you mean my code is doing its job correctly? @cramopy

Comment: yes, I think so. Only the program itself can be hidden this way, if it is a console program only. if the program is creating windows from itself, there is no possibility to block this from your site, except the programmer allows you to do so. An example would be (not working for firefox) a extra flag/parameter to pass to th program: i.e. `-no-windows`. but this has to be coded into the program by the programmer.

Comment: @cramopy what about other languages ? like C or C++?

Comment: these problem stays the same over all languages, if the intial programmer did not include this feature to his/her source code. you are not able to stop a program from creating windows, if the programs does not want you to be able to do so. at least not with the start process method. you can of course hide the created windows as haitam says, but this is another approach than preventing this from the start process method.

Comment: I don't think Firefox is designed to be automated without UI interaction. Please reconsider if this is really the right way to solve your underlying problem. If you tell us what your underlying problem is, the community might be able to offer alternative suggestions.

Comment: You would *want* to see it in Task Manager, it's still a legitimate process regardless of what window station it's running under. What do you exactly want to do with it, and can you not use a headless browser like Awesomium or PhantomJS instead?

Comment: @Heinzi firefox is just an example

Comment: @Farshadhn: I see. Still, it doesn't make a difference: You should not do this with applications that do not explicitly support unattended automation.

Comment: @Lloyd we wana make a windows service to run a specific application for all computers. we dont wana bother any one so we want to make it hidden and do something for us. this program has an interface so we want to make it hidden and work in background.

Comment: @Heinzi this is what i am obliged to do in our company. needs to run an application that is automatic in background in a hidden way

Comment: You could also try something like NSSM - https://nssm.cc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can make use of PInvoke and call the `ShowWindow` API to Hide/Show the process' window.

After you have created your process, you can get its `MainWindowHandle` and use it to call `ShowWindow` to either `HIDE = 0` the window or `SHOW = 5` the window.

More informations on the API here: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.showwindow

An example of use here: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/845159/csharp-hide-show-process-window

Note that if you hide a window using `ShowWindow`, you'll have to save the old `WindowHandle` because you will not be able to get it from the `Process`.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: this is a good answer. but it needs time. when i do it in ctur it needs at list 1000 ms waiting and after that it can make it hidden. is there any way to do it in a faster way?

Comment: I don't think so :/